# Vectorize pairwise edit distance computation

Tags: python, performance, numpy, edit-distance

How can I vectorize this function? It takes an array of array of tuples as input and computes the distance between elements using Levenshtein's method. I found some simpler examples but they weren't of much use for me since I couldn't apply the same logic for my problem. Any help with making this code more efficient will be appreciated!

```
def sim_mat(sequence):
    sim_mat = np.empty(sequence.shape[0], sequence.shape[0])
    for i in range(sequence.shape[0]):
        for j in range(i, sequence.shape[0]):
            distance = levenshtein(sequence[i], sequence[j])
            sim_mat [i, j] = sim_mat [j, i] = distance
    return sim_mat
```

**EDIT:** Here is the levenshtein function that we use to compute the distance:

```
def levenshtein(seq1, seq2):
    m = len(seq1)
    n = len(seq2)
    dp = [[0]*(n + 1)]*(m + 1))
    for i in range(1, m + 1):
        dp[i][0] = get_sequence_length(seq1[:i])
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        dp[0][j] = get_sequence_length(seq2[:j])
    for i in range(m + 1):
        for j in range(n + 1):
            if seq1[i - 1] == seq2[j - 1]:
                dp[i][j] = dp[i - 1][j - 1]
            else:
                dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j - 1] + len(seq2[j - 1]),  # Insert
                               dp[i - 1][j] + len(seq1[i - 1]),  # Remove
                               dp[i - 1][j - 1] + max(len(sets_difference(seq1[i - 1], seq2[j - 1])),
                                                      len(sets_difference(seq2[j - 1], seq1[i - 1]))))
    return dp[m][n]
```

and `get_sequence_length`:

```
def get_sequence_length(sequence):
    return sum(map(len, sequence))
```

EDIT2: `sets_difference`

```
def sets_difference(set1, set2):
    return list(set(set1).difference(set2))
```

An example sequence would look like this:

```
[[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('c', 'd')], [('b', 'd', 'f')]]
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm not sure if the question as it stands is suited for Code Review, since there is very little context to create a meaningful review. Nevertheless a wild suggestion: Have you already tried [`scipy.spatial.distance.cdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html#scipy.spatial.distance.cdist) (or `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist`) with `levenstein` as "custom" metric? But looking at the implementation of it, I don't have much hope that you could expect better performance.

Comment: @greybeard you're right, we don't need the full matrix, only the upper half of it.

Comment: What are some realistic lengths for your sequences? If they all were as short as the example, there is likely not a lot of potential to see benefits from vectorization.

Comment: @AlexV At the moment we have 100k sequences, each sequence has up to 10 tuples and up to 5 elements in a tuple.  If vectorization is not the way to go, is there any other way to improve the performance?

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for the link, we'll adjust the code accordinlgy but I don't think it will improve the speed by much. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @greybeard I don't think I quite get what you mean by handling pairs independently, can you elaborate? We also thought about using numba, though it doesn't seem very easy to do either. If you find time, any help will be appreciated!

Comment: There's tactic, and there's strategy - check out [python-Levenshtein](https://pypi.org/project/python-Levenshtein/). What I (ineptly) tried to get at: is there anything to be gained trying to evaluate *edit distances within a set of sequences* over *evaluating each and every pair independently*.

Comment: @greybeard I added ```sets_difference```. To answer the other question: we have a list of sequences of patterns. We need to compute the similarity matrix to form clusters from them.

Comment: Putting first two conditions before the main loop helped a bit. We tried to use numba but to no avail, same story with moving the function to R and using many parallel packages, though they hardly ever worked on windows, and if they did, something must have been off since it took more time than without using multiple cores.

Comment: Moreover, we use a custom function to compute the distance, since deleting an element from tuple costs less than removing a whole tuple, meaning the operations are weighted.

Comment: (Dang. I put off trying to see *Levenshtein* in `min(…, …, … + max(len(sets_difference(seq1[i - 1], seq2[j - 1])), …` for hours because I missed `custom function to compute the distance` - *IFF* you use some "modified Levenshtein distance", can you please point that out prominently in your question? (and use *edit distance* in the title in case - as a tag, anyway.) For starters, it rules out using ready-to-go solutions *as-is*.)

Comment: Look what the cat brought in: [space conscious Levenshtein implementation](https://github.com/paralax/ClassyBadger/blob/master/oops.py) (limitation to "34" is a misconception, sort of - makes me wonder if the assert and the argument default are from the same person.) Might want to try a few timings: can you provide a *generator* for suitable test data?

Comment: When there is something that promises more helpful answers, don't comment comments: edit your question. - There's different routes to follow: *speed up distance computation for pairs of sequences*, *speed up the computation of all distances within a set of sequences* possibly with a *bound*, use tools ([python-string-similarity](https://pypi.org/project/strsim/) looks worth looking into), using *trie*s or *suffix array*s for the set problem, investigate *(k-)nearest neighbour* or *clustering* directly. *How to vectorise an intermediate level* looks an XY-problem.

Comment: Line 3 in the `levenshtein` function should be `dp = [[0]*(n + 1)]*(m + 1)`, there is one closing parenthesis too many.

Comment: Also, your function does not work with the given example, the first line in your `sim_mat` function probably needs to be `sim_mat = np.empty((sequence.shape[0], sequence.shape[0]))` and the example needs to be a `np.array`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think vectorisation to buy you anything "in the upper levels".
My guess is the statement [little use due to data dependencies](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wagner%E2%80%93Fischer_algorithm#Possible_modifications) is true even more than for 
*parallel computing* in general.
With SciPy/NumPy I'm out of my depth; drawing on [Syncrossus levenshtein.py](https://gist.github.com/Syncrossus/b7dbb063fa227b410563be123cb93549).
I'd need a better motivation for the distance function - I guess the minimum requirement being *triangle inequality*
Shot from the hip using `set.symmetric_difference()` as food for thought:

```
import numpy as np


def replacement_cost(s1, s2):
    return len(set(s1).symmetric_difference(s2))


def edit_distance(seq1, seq2):
    """ return edit distance between two list-like sequences of sequences
        Args:
            seq1, seq2: subscriptable objects compatible with len()
                containing objects comparable with the `==` operator.
    """
    m = len(seq1)
    n = len(seq2)
    dp = np.zeros(shape=(m, n))
    dp[0, :] = range(0, n)
    dp[:, 0] = range(0, m)

    for i in range(1, m):
        for j in range(1, n):
            cost = 0 if seq1[i] == seq2[j] \
                     else replacement_cost(seq1[i], seq2[j])
            dp[i][j] = min(dp[i][j - 1] + len(seq2[j - 1]),  # Insert
                           dp[i - 1][j] + len(seq1[i - 1]),  # Remove
                           dp[i - 1][j - 1] + cost)          # Replace
    return dp[m-1][n-1]
```

Comment: Using NumPy in `edit_distance()` suffers from the same circumstance as vectorisation: your sequences are short, but you got a shi[tp]load of those.

Comment: It looks *wrong* to create the sets from the tuples over and again.